# How to use TransactWriteItems of DynamoDB (do transactions) with an Angular/nodejs Amplify App

Tags: node.js, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

## Context

I'm working on a crowdfunding platform in which people can create a commitment for a campaign they want to invest in. It's a commitment because unless people commit enough money to reach the funding goal, their funds should not be transferred to the campaign developer.

A commitment involves multiple records being either read, created or updated, since it involves changing the money committed to the campaign, the wallet funds of the user and create the commitment (or update it, if they are committing more money).

These are, at the moment, individual mutations that are being sent by a Lambda Resolver which access the AppSync API and does them sequentially to ensure that if any mutation fails, the transaction as a whole should be rolled back.

## My particular question:

Since DynamoDB supports "transactions" with TransactWriteItems, Amplify uses DynamoDB and gives access to it using AppSync, how can I use the TransactWriteItems functionality inside of this Lambda Resolver to avoid implementing custom rollback logic ?

Below is the handler for the Lambda resolver and an auxiliary function that is inside of a LambdaLayer, which handles the actual request and response to the AppSync API.

I've researched on custom VTL resolvers but 1. I don't have any experience with VTL and 2. the auxiliary function in the lambda layer is there to reduce redundant code. A lot of the business logic requires the same logic to send requests to the AppSync API and I would like this solution to have the possibility to be expanded depending on our legal requirements.

The Handler of my Lambda resolver at the moment:

```
const { createInvestment } = require('./createInvestment');
const { getWallet } = require('./getWallet');
const { updateCampaign } = require('./updateCampaign');
const { updateInvestment } = require('./updateInvestment');
const { updateWallet } = require('./updateWallet');
const { sendEmail } = require('./sendEmail');

/**
 *
 * @param {Object} args
 * @returns {Array} Array of responses of all queries and mutations
 */
exports.processInvestment = async args => {
  const parameters = args[1];
  const responsesArray = [];

  let previousInvestmentAmount = 0;
  try {
    const walletInfo = await getWallet(parameters.walletID);
    if (parameters.createInvestment) {
      await createInvestment(
        responsesArray,
        parameters.userID,
        parameters.campaignID,
        parameters.investmentAmount,
        walletInfo.id
      );
    } else {
      const previousAmount = await updateInvestment(
        responsesArray,
        parameters.investmentID,
        parameters.investmentAmount,
        parameters.investmentVersion,
        parameters.movementID,
        parameters.movementVersion
      );
      previousInvestmentAmount = previousAmount;
    }

    await updateWallet(
      responsesArray,
      previousInvestmentAmount,
      walletInfo.id,
      walletInfo.committed,
      walletInfo.available,
      parameters.investmentAmount,
      walletInfo._version
    );

    await updateCampaign(responsesArray, parameters.campaignID);

    const emailInfo = {
      userID: parameters.userID,
      campaignID: parameters.campaignID,
      amount: parameters.investmentAmount,
    };

    await sendEmail(emailInfo);
    return responsesArray;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error processing investment', err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Function to send query/mutation to the AppSync API:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const graphql = require('graphql');
const { print } = graphql;

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_TERRENTA_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
const GRAPHQL_API_KEY = process.env.API_TERRENTA_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT;

/**
 *
 * @param {Object} pQuery
 * @param {Object} pVariables
 * @returns {Object} Api response object
 */
exports.apiQuery = async function (pQuery, pVariables) {
  try {
    const axiosRequest = {
      url: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': GRAPHQL_API_KEY,
      },
      data: {
        query: print(pQuery),
      },
    };

    if (pVariables) {
      axiosRequest.data.variables = pVariables;
    }

    const queryResponse = await axios(axiosRequest);

    if (!queryResponse || !queryResponse.data.data) {
      if (queryResponse.data.errors)
        console.error(`Error on API Request`, queryResponse.data.errors);
      throw new Error(`Error on API Request`);
    }

    return queryResponse;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error during API transaction', err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

*Sidenote:* Each method inside of the handler not only calls the apiQuery function to send the request to AppSync, in some cases they have to do additional business logic to build the query/mutation.